# Opera just imported everything from Chrome, including authentication tokens. How can I protect my Chrome profile folders?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, security, browser, opera

I've recently installed [Opera](https://www.opera.com/) browser in unattended mode (using Chocolatey: `choco install opera`). When I opened it for the first time, Opera had all my bookmarks imported from Chrome (unwanted, but OK).

Then I clicked on `GMail` in the Opera bookmark bar, **and to my huge surprise, it loaded my Gmail account without asking me to authenticate first**. I was able to read my email as though I was still in Chrome.

Apparently, Opera has somehow imported my Google account OAuth2 tokens from my Chrome profile under `"%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data\..."` and it's able to make a use of them, perhaps because it also uses Chromium as its rendering engine.

IMO, this is a problem with how Chrome protects its local user profile data. To me, it's both undesirable and scary. I would at least expect Chrome to use something like [Windows Data Protection API (DAPI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Protection_API) to encrypt its sensitive data.

Is there any way I can prevent other programs (like Opera) form poking their noses into my Chrome local profile, besides by not installing them?

---

**Updated, I reported this to Chrome team, and they have dismissed the issue for the following reason: [Why aren't physically-local attacks in Chrome’s threat model?](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/security/faq.md#Why-arent-physically_local-attacks-in-Chromes-threat-model)**

Ironically, **remedies like [PKCE](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7636) have been put in place to protect access tokens from malicious local actors in the OAuth2 authorization flow**. I struggle to understand how existence of PKCE sides with Chrome's stance on local attacks.

I personally don't think the mitigation of that attack vector should be completely ignored. From a user prospective, as soon as I've provided my password to Chrome for encrypted data sync'ing, I'd expect it to be stored using the underlying OS API for storing secrets.

[DPAPI](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dpapi/), being that API for Windows, can't fully protect applications from each other, but it does rather a good job mitigating that. It presets the user with a standard OS dialog, requesting to authorize the access:

[image: DPAPI prompt]

This screenshot is from running an [example from the online DPAPI docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccrypto/example-c-program-using-cryptprotectdata). **Note how the system UI shows the location of the app trying to access the secret**, so it's my choice as an informed user whether to grant the access or not.

Of course, a malware can still spoof that UI, but this is not something that a legit, code-signed and generally trusted software like Opera would do. **If Chrome used DPAPI, Opera would have to use it too, for their import-from-Chrome feature to work.** Invoked by Opera, the DPAPI UI would prompt me to authorize the access to Chrome's local data, and I would have an option to reject it.

---

**Updated**, [there's a sign](https://www.reddit.com/r/chrome/comments/dg6em1/chrome_doest_take_any_efforts_to_protect_its/f3bw6b4/) that Chromium team may address this issue in the future.

Comment: Does installing Opera from its official installer also imports Chrome's auth tokens?

Comment: @Biswapriyo, yes it does, all checkboxes are ticked by default: https://imgur.com/mAjXQx2.

Comment: Here's the full installer link at the time of posting this: https://get.geo.opera.com/pub/opera/desktop/63.0.3368.71/win/Opera_63.0.3368.71_Setup_x64.exe

Comment: These days Opera is just a reskinned Chrome. So its not even really a local attack. You read Chrome's data with one version of Chrome, or another version of Chrome. I don't really see how we can help answer the question as, as you say, it comes down to Google's programming.

Comment: @SirAdelaide, I tend to agree there's not much we can do, although I'm still not happy that anything I might be running on my PC could potentially read/exploit my Chrome tokens. Also, while [I'm not the only one concerned](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39749694/1768303), I'm surprised most people don't see this as a Chrome issue. I even considered using Chrome under a separate dedicated user account (e.g.: `RUNAS /user:ChromeUser "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"`), and giving up on using it as the default browser for external links.

Comment: Ideas : (1) Run Chrome under a another user account and only give this account permission to access the Chrome folder, (2) Stash away the Chrome folder in a safe place, for example a sandbox of [Sandboxie](https://www.sandboxie.com/) and run Chrome via Sandboxie.

Comment: @harrymc, I must have lived under a rock as I've never heard of Sandboxie. Sounds like Docker for GUI apps :)

Comment: Sandboxie is a security product for isolating suspicious programs, redirecting their file and registry modifications into a sandbox area and not into the real system. A product that discovers that your Chrome folder is in `C:\path` will still be blocked because no such folder will exist inside the "normal" file system, but only in the "shadow" file system.